Powershell Send-MailMessage with Outlook SMTP Server and App Passwords
I was using a simple Powershell script to send me an Email notification when a PC has rebooted unattended.
To do so I was using the following code:
Send-MailMessage -To 'NN@outlook.com' -From 'NN@outlook.com' -Subject 'PC rebooted' -Body 'PC has rebooted' -Credential $Credential -SmtpServer 'smtp-mail.outlook.com' -UseSsl -Port 587

This script does not work anymore. The error message is:

Client not authenticated to send mail. Error: 535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, basic authentication is disabled. [MR2P264CA0045.FRAP264.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM 2024-09-27T09:31:21.410Z 08DCDE4F90DFC7E4]

After Microsoft has changed a few days ago that basic authentication is no longer available for their mail servers I learned that one can use so called "App Passwords" that are meant e.g. for older devices like cable modems (e.g. Fritz!Box) that don't support modern authentication methods. My understanding of this is that I can use the same SMTP server, port and security configuration and as before, my email address but the new created App-Password as credentials.
So I created an App-Password in my Outlook Account and used it within the script in the hope that this would work as before. This is however not the case. I get the same error message when using the App-Password.
Has anyone an idea or solution how to send a simple notification vie an outlook.com email account with the changed authentication policy? It seems that the problem is the same most email providers like yahoo, iCloud, etc.
I tried various App-Passwords, created it with the browser running on the same PC I wanted to use the App-Password on, contacted and spend hours in the MS Support chat
